# Suppose $U \subset S \subset X$. Show that the closure of U in S is equal to $cl(U) \cap S$.

Tags: general-topology

This is from James E. Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, exercise 3.7.

Here is what I have:

Clearly $cl_S(U) \cap S = cl_S(U)$, which leads me to believe that $cl_S(U) \cap S = cl(U) \cap S$. I have been stuck trying to prove this but I am not getting anywhere. I'm sure I have to use the definition of subspace topology on S but I am not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $cl U \cap S$ is a closed set of S that contains $U$. Let $C$ be a closed set of S that contains U. Then $C=C'\cap S$ where C' is closed in X. Now $C'$ is a closed subset of $X$ that contains $U$, so $cl U \subset C'$. It follows that $cl U \cap S \subset C'\cap S=C$. This means that $cl U \cap S$ is the smallest closed  set of $S$ that contains $U$, so it is equal to $cl_S(U)$.

Answer (score -2):

Let $x\in \overline U$, such that $x\notin S$. Then, since $U\subset S$, we have that $x\notin U$, which is false, because $U\subset \overline U$; so $x\in \overline U\cap S$. We prooved that $\overline U \subset \overline U\cap S$. The other inclusion is trivial, since $x\in \overline U\cap S\Rightarrow x\in \overline U$. q.e.d.